# Is it possible to slice a list and write it back to a YAML file with YQ

Tags: yaml, yq

If I have a file like this:

```
name: test
host: test.com
region: us-east-1
plannedMaintenancePeriods:
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
```

Is it possible to replace the list with a sliced version, where `plannedMaintenancePeriods` only contains 5 entries?

I have tried this:

`yq -i '.plannedMaintenancePeriods=.plannedMaintenancePeriods[0:4]' ${TENANT_METADATA_FILE}`

But it seems to write the top level map into the plannedMaintenancePeriods list like so:

```
name: test
host: test.com
region: us-east-1
plannedMaintenancePeriods: !!map
  - name
  - test
  - host
  - test.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the update operator `|=`. As it carries the context, you also don't have to repeat the path. You can even omit the `0` at the beginning of the range, but the end is always non-inclusive, so to get 5 items you have to go up to `5`:

```bash
yq -i '.plannedMaintenancePeriods |= .[:5]' file.yaml
```

```yaml
name: test
host: test.com
region: us-east-1
plannedMaintenancePeriods:
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
  - startTime: 1679987700
    endTime: 1679992500
```